# When people say OP what does it mean?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many posts where people refer to the OP of the question. So what does OP stand for? is it the asker of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OP** means **O** riginal **P** oster of the question or answer.

Comment: There were a lot of more-or-less irrelevant comments here, which I've [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31626/discussion-on-answer-by-user36790-when-people-say-op-what-does-it-mean) to avoid distracting from the post.